# conditional checkmark or cross mark in HTML based on a variable coming from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm very new to the whole HTML, JS, and CSS world. What I am trying to accomplish is to read a variable from Javascript and based on that display a green checkmark or a red cross mark next to an existing image, 'robot.ico' in an empty box, 'box-feed'.

Here is my HTML:

```
     <div class='robot-info'>
          <b>{{robot.name}}</b>
          <img src='robot.ico' class='robot-img'/>
          <div class='box-feed' v-bind:style='{display: nextVisibility}'>
            <div v-bind:class='[robot.rFeedBack]'></div>
            --- here I should put the check mark or cross mark---  
          </div>

        </div>
```

[robot.rFeedBack] returns either `checkMark` or `crossMark`.
I have another variable coming from javascript called robot.rSymbole.
[robot.rSymbole] returns either the HTML code for check mark (✔) or cross mark(✕).

Here is the CSS:

```
.box-feed {
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: -5px;
padding-top: 10px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
background-size: cover;
} 


.checkMark{
 position: relative;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 background: transparent 1px;
 color: green;
 content: \2714;
  }

   .crossMark{
    position: relative;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: transparent 1px;
    color: red;
    content: \2715;

  }
```

I even tried to use the image of a green check mark and a red cross mark and read the name of the correct image to be displayed from js, but it says it couldn't find the image \adress\to\my\server['robots.mark']. robots.mark returns the checkMark.ico or crossMark.ico that both exist in the path.

[image: check mark when [robot.rFeedBack] returns checkMark and red cross mark when [robot.rFeedBack] returns crossMark]

I very much apperiace any help.

Comment: Could you please post a minimal demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/vue?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by displaying the image of red-crossmark or green-checkmark.

HTML:

```
<img id='box-feed' src='' v-bind:class='robot.rFeedBack' v-bind:style='{display: nextVisibility}'/>
```

In Javascrip:

```
document.getElementById('box-feed').setAttribute('src','check-mark.ico');
document.getElementById('box-feed').setAttribute('src','cross-mark.ico');
```

Each of the lines in Javascript are called based on the condition I would like to use for displaying the appropriate mark.

I still need to know how to show the checkmark and cross mark using HTML codes without displaying the image for each cross mark or check mark.

Any ideas?